# Powershell script to display all Users in a Group AD

Tags: powershell, adgroup

I have created the below

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=Domain,dc=.com" -properties name, members | 
    Select-Object *,@{Name='Member';Expression={$_.Members -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'}} | 
    FT Name, Member -Autosize | 
    out-file c:\text.txt
```

Ignore Domain and .com I have them populated with my relevant information, but for sake of here removed them.

When I run this it returns what I'm after but when looking at the members within the group they all end with ... and don't show all the members

Comment: Pipe into a csv instead. It's format-table that is trucating the output inorder to display it. `Select-Object props | Export-CSV -NoType c:\text.txt`

Comment: That export-csv garbles all the text file :( "9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3",,,,,
"27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,
"27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,

Comment: Replace `FT Name, Member -Autosize` with `Out-String` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to correct. Let's look at them in order. The actual AD query can be simplified: you only need to specify 'Members' as an additional property to retrieve as 'Name' is brought back by default:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=Domain,dc=.com" -properties members
```

Given that you only want to output two properties ('Name' and your custom one 'Member'), use your select to retrieve only the ones you want:

```
Select-Object Name ,@{Name='Member';Expression={$_.Members -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'}}
```

Remove the Format-Table: we have already limited the selection in the previous command. Format cmdlets are designed to format the output to the console window and best practice dictates that they should only be used for that purpose and that they should always be the last element of a pipeline.

Piping all of that to Export-Csv will then produce what you want:

```
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\text.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I was after, still trying to get my head around powershell as only just started to look into it.

On a side note is there a way to expand on the -filter to only include part of a group name?

Comment: The filter parameter will make your AD queries faster as using it will limit the scope of that query. In short it's something like this: `Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "SomeGroupNamePrefix*"'`. I'd advise looking at the help for the cmdlet: `Get-Help Get-ADGroup -Full`

Comment: I'd be grateful for the vote if you have found this uesful

Answer (score 1):

This one did the trick for me

> Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators | Select-Object name, objectClass,distinguishedName | Export-CSV -Path “adgroupmembers.csv”

I got this here.

[https://www.lepide.com/how-to/export-members-of-a-particular-ad-group-using-poweshell.html#:~:text=The%20PowerShell%20Get%2DADGroupMember%20cmdlet,group%20you%20want%20to%20use](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/export-members-of-a-particular-ad-group-using-poweshell.html#:%7E:text=The%20PowerShell%20Get%2DADGroupMember%20cmdlet,group%20you%20want%20to%20use).